# what is bad_alloc and why does output screen does not shows all the values

Tags: c++

I wrote a program for infinite loop as follows and constantly allocated new memory

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
    {
        double* x = new double[2000];
        *x = i * 2.5;
        cout << i <<"  "<< *x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It ran successfully and it ended at the end saying bad_alloc.

```
133415  333538
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I think this states that there is no more memory.
Please tell if what I think is correct or not. 
And the output screen also doesn't shows all the values from zero but rather it starts from 133125.
Why is it so?

Comment: _It ran successfully_ according to you it did?

Comment: Yes my main aim was to check that when the memory allocation stops....so it stopped at 133415 but I just asked the meaning of the error and why does the output screen not shows the value from zero and rather 133125.....

Comment: Just trying to increase my knowledge.....didn't know people got hurt while doing that :P....

Comment: why are you using raw pointers and naked `new` & `delete` in your program ? Stop using them. What are you trying to do ? you program contains memory leak

Comment: Please understand the question!!!!

Comment: i am currently doing bjarne stroustrup book at there is a question which tells me to do so......my simple question is that why does the output screen shows me values from 0 to 133415  and shows me from 133125 to 133415.

Comment: doesn't shows me values from 0 to 133415 and shows me from 133125 to 133415.

Comment: try outputting to a file (and flush each write) and you should see all values unless there really is a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you ran out of memory. You are currently allocating a new 2000 double array in each iteration of an endless loop. As written, your program will not end on its own excepting when it uses all of your available memory.

As for the lack of early values, I would suspect they are scrolling out of the display buffer for your console window.